# How to perform request with MultiSearch API in Jest?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I need to make some request with the MultiSearch API from [Jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/master/jest-common/src/main/java/io/searchbox/core/MultiSearch.java).
I tried to build Search request like this :

`Search search = new Search.Builder(query).addIndex(index).addType(type).build();`

And then, I add all these requests into a collection, to build the MultiSearch and get the result, like this :

```
List<Search> ms = new ArrayList<Search>();
for (#iterate over#) {
    ms.add(search())
    //Adding the searches queries to the List
}
MultiSearch multi = new MultiSearch.Builder(ms).build();
MultiSearchResult multir = client.execute(multi);
```

But this return this error from elasticsearch :

```
{
    "error": {
        "caused_by": {
            "reason": "Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@2ccf4bb6; line: 1, column: 1])\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@2ccf4bb6; line: 2, column: 3]",
            "type": "json_e_o_f_exception"
        },
        "reason": "Exception when parsing search request",
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "reason": "Exception when parsing search request",
                "type": "parse_exception"
            }
        ],
        "type": "parse_exception"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

So my question is, how to perform MultiSearch request with jest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after tests, I found a solution :

```
Search search = new Search.Builder(query.toString().replaceAll("\\n|\\r", "")).addIndex(es_index_data)
                .addType(es_type_data).build();
```